# Inverse of a matrix of one.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, matrix-calculus

I have to show that a matrix of one, denoted $J_n$ is not invertible.

To begin with I proved by going back to the definition that $J_n^2 = nJ_n$ but now I have to deduce from this that $J_n$ is not invertible.

Does anyone have a clue ?

Comment: I am a bit stuck, but I think we can say that $J_n$ cannot be the inverse of $J_n$, because it will not be equal to $I_n$. But then, I don't understand how to proof that $J_n$ has no inverse where the inverse would be a "random" matrix.

Comment: Suppose that $J_n$ is invertible then multiplying by $J_n^{-1}$  :
$$J_n^2 J_n^{-1} = n J_n J_n^{-1}$$
then :
$$J_n = n I_n$$
Absurd.

Answer (score 2):

The matrix has row rank $1$ and so is singular if $n>1$.

Note that the 2x2 matrix $A=2I$ is invertible and yet $A^2=2A$ so it is not possible to argue from $J_n^2 = nJ_n$ only.

Comment: Yeah, but it is not using the fact that $J_n^2 = nJ_n$, no ? I suppose I should use that...

Comment: It's not possible to do this. See the addition to my answer.